# improving performance of mysql stored function

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a stored function I ported from SQL Server that is super slow for MySql.  Since my application needs to support both SQL Server and MySql ( via ODBC drivers ), I sort of require this function.  The stored function is normally used in the "where" clause, but it is slow even when it is only in the "select" clause.

Are there any tricks for improving the performance of functions?  Maybe any helpful tools that point out potential stored function problems or slow points?

They are complex functions.  So while one statement in the function is relatively quick, everything put together is slow.

Also, views are used inside these functions.  Don't know how much that impacts things.  The views themselves seem to run in a reasonable time.

I know I am not giving much specifics, but I am more looking for a performance tool or some high level stored function performance tips.

I did see various posts online advising people not to use functions in "where" clauses, but I am sort of stuck since I want to go back and forth between SQL Server and MySql with the same executable, and the functions are to complex to embed directly into the SQL in my application.

Edit based on Gruber answer, to clarify things with an example:
Here is an example query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM inv USE INDEX(inv_invsku) WHERE invsku >= 'PBM116-01' AND WHMSLayer_IS_LOC_ACCESSIBLE( '', 'PFCSYS    ', invloc ) > 0 ORDER BY invsku;
```

If I get rid of the call to IS_LOC_ACCESSIBLE, it is considerably faster.  IS_LOC_ACCESSIBLE is just one of 3 such functions.  It has a bunch of IF statements, queries of other tables and views, etc.  That is why I call it "complex", because of all that extra logic and conditional paths.

Comment: MySQL will call that function for every row that otherwise matches the WHERE clause.  The optimizer will not pull any code out of the function to make the whole SELECT run any faster.  The best we can do is look at the function and see if (1) we can speed it up, or (2) somehow pull what it is doing out of the function and do it more efficiently.  Are you willing to show us the function, plus SHOW CREATE TABLE/VIEW?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a query profiler, for instance the one included in [dbForge Studio](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/features.html#profiler), and try to figure out exactly what the bottlenecks are.

Maybe your tables aren't properly indexed?

You can sometimes achieve good improvements in MySQL (and SQL Server) by moving things around in your queries, creating identical output but changing the internal execution path. For instance, try removing the complex WHERE clause, use the complex code as output from a wrapped SELECT statement which you can use WHERE on subsequently.

Comment: I am still processing your answer, but hopefully my update clarifies things.  I tried your subquery idea ( or at least my interpretation of the idea ), and that did not help.

Comment: Does a query profiler look at the actual functions used, or just the query that uses the function?  All the profilers I know of just look at the query, not at the functions being called in the query.  What I really need is a function profiler.

Comment: For your "moving things around" idea, how would you suggest I do that?  I gave you an example select statement, which I then took and tried your sub-query idea ( or at least my interpretation of your idea ).

Comment: Use the `WHMSLayer_IS_LOC_ACCESSIBLE` function call as the output of an inner `SELECT` statement and use it in an outer `SELECT` statement to perform the `WHERE` filtering. Just a long shot.